# Sending data from several arrays to a second view controller by clicking a table cell

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have a table that lists audio titles. I want to click on a title and it takes me to a second view controller that displays the audio title, a picture, a description and a play button.

I have 4 arrays created each holding all the relevant data but I can't get the labels, imageView and button on the second view controller to change to what ever row is clicked on my table.

Here is a sample of my code for the first view controller:

```
let audioTitile = ["Bubbling Pools", "March Of Faith"]

let audioImage = ["1.png", "2.png"]

let desc = ["The stench of life fills the air. Viscous fluid bubbles to the surface in great exhortations of gas and moisture. Something about these pools is familiar..",
            "The devoted stream into the distance. The dust from their sandaled feet blocks out the sun for miles around. There's no stopping them. They believe."]

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return audioTitle.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = audioTitle[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: audioTitle[indexPath.row])
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let temp = segue.destination as! SecondViewController

        temp.titleLabel.text = audioTitle[0] // need to replace [0] with ?
       // temp.artworkImage.image = audioImage[0] This Code is wrong
        temp.descriptionLabel.text = desc[0] // need to replace [0] with ?


    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }   
}
```

My Second View Controller Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var artworkImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        playAudio()

    }

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    func playAudio() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "2_Bubbling_Pools.mp3", withExtension: "mp3")!

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }

            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pack arrays in some way. You can transit arrays in several ways, but the most correct way - create struct or class. Add struct like this:

```
struct Audio {
var title: String
var imageName: String
var descr: String }
```

Then in first ViewController, initialize array:

```
let audios = [Audio(title: "Bubbling Pools", imageName: "1.png", descr: "The stench of life fills the air. Viscous fluid bubbles "),
           Audio(title: "March Of Faith", imageName: "2.png", descr: "The stench of life fills the air. Viscous fluid bubbles ")]
```

Then change your FirstVC like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return audios.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let audio = audios[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = audio.title
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let audio = audios[indexPath.row]

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: audio)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {

        let audio = sender as! Audio
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SeconViewController
        destinationVC.selectedAudio = audio
    }
}
```

And change your SecondVC like this:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var artworkImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

var selectedAudio: Audio!

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // CONFIGURE LABELS HERE USING selectedAudio

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks so much for this reply, this makes sense now but I do have one problem in my second view controller at this line of code: var selectedAudio: Audio!  use of undeclared type 'Audio'

Comment: You should place this code in separate Audio.swift file:
struct Audio {
var title: String
var imageName: String
var descr: String }

Comment: that worked great but I noticed I had set everything in my struct as Strings which was incorrect, I got my images working by changing to this var imageName: UIImage but not sure what I should change var audioURL: String to this is meant to be my audio file, all I have here is a String of the name of my audio file

Comment: You can use any type in Audio struct. Image, String whatever. I just suggested string array of image names, because it's exactly how you do in your example, when use let audioImage = ["1.png", "2.png"]